# Magento 2 Rest API: getting error "Invalid attribute name: %1"

Tags: magento2, rest-api

Trying to get product with id using rest api search criteria:

```
Request: http://magento_host/rest/V1/products?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=id&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=3&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=eq
```

Getting response:

```
{
  "message": "Invalid attribute name: %1",
  "parameters": [
    "id"
  ]
}
```

WHY?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try with `[filters][0][field]=entity_id` instead of `[filters][0][field]=id`