# Magento2 product list API not working

Tags: magento2, rest-api

I am trying to get product list using category ID but it's not working,

My Request:

```
http://mysite/m2/rest/default/V1/products?searchCriteria[filterGroups][][filters][][field]=category_id&searchCriteria[filterGroups][][filters][][value]=3&searchCriteria[filterGroups][][filters][][conditionType]=eq&searchCriteria[sortOrders][][field]=created_at&searchCriteria[sortOrders][][direction]=DESC&searchCriteria[pageSize]=10&searchCriteria[currentPage]=1
```

My Reponse:

```
{
  "message": "Invalid attribute name: %1",
  "parameters": [
    null
  ]
}
```

Please tell me what's wrong with the parameters, I tried this too but no luck, [Magento 2 Rest API: getting error "Invalid attribute name: %1"](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/182153/magento-2-rest-api-getting-error-invalid-attribute-name-1)

Answer (score 0):

```
rest/all/V1/products?searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0]  [field]=name&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][value]=%25Bag%25&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][conditionType]=like&searchCriteria[pageSize]=10&searchCriteria[currentPage]=1
```